# WebClient.UploadData is returning control characters after non-ascii characters

Tags: c#, encoding, webclient

I'm using WebClient.UploadData to send data to another server and get data back. Whenever data comes back that has a non-ascii character in it like an a with an accent on top, it comes back with other characters after it. Is there any way to set the encoding to prevent this?

I tried set the encoding to UTF8. I thought it would fix it, but it didn't.

Comment: Do not use WebClient, its depricated. Use HttpClient.